# Using variable in expression in arcpy CalculateField tool

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I want to use the following expression in the arcpy.CalculateField_management tool.

I have a variable called "value" and a field called "Field01"

I want to use (value - Field01) / 20

I can´t seem to find the correct syntax with arcpy.CalculateField_management.

arcpy.CalculateField_management (fc, "test",expression, "PYTHON")

Given error is:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

I have tried the following and many other combinations:

```
expression = value - "!XKoordInt!" / 20

expression = "("+value+"-!XKoordInt!)/20")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second listed expression is close:

```python
expression = "({0} - !XKoordInt!)/20".format(value)
```

Using the `format` method is generally better than string concatenation, it will take care of different input types and formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `format` method to put the `value` into the expression. Using triple quotes will make it easier to have quotes inside the expression, too.

```
value = 5000
expression = '''({0} - !XKoord!) / 20'''.format(value)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table=fc, field='test',
                                expression=expression, expression_type='PYTHON_9.3')
```