# Concatenate string variable and field in ArcPy "CalculateField" expression

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, error-000539

I am trying to add a file path field to a feature layer in an ArcPy notebook in ArcGIS Pro. I have a variable with the beginning of the path (the path to the folder) and an existing field with the file name. I have been looking at other questions on here and on ArcGIS help websites (e.g. [How to use variable in expression in arcpy CalculateField tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198140)) but haven't found a way that works. If we pretend the folder is just my downloads folder, here is what I have tried as expressions within the arcpy.management.CalculateField command:

```
output_folder = "C:/Users/ellah/Downloads/"

expression = 'output_folder + !match.Filename!'
expression = str(output_folder) + '!match.Filename!'
expression = " ".join([str(i) for i in [output_folder, !match.Filename!] if i])
expression = "{}/{}".format(output_folder, !match.Filename!)
expression = "{0} + str(!match.Filename!)".format(output_folder)
```

... as well as some other small tweaks. I've tried using them as the expression as well as defining them as a function in the code block and running them that way. Everything works fine if I type out the actual folder path ('C:/Users/ellah/Downloads/') rather than calling the variable. I don't think it's an issue with the forward/backslashes or typos like a double slash.

Some errors I have gotten include:

ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'output_folder' is not defined

ERROR 000539:   File "", line 1
C:/Users/ellah/Downloads/out/u"1_in.png"
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Have you tried `import os, os.path.join(output_folder,'!match.Filename!')`?

Comment: @aldo_tapia That certainly seems helpful. Are you imagining it within the expression or code block in arcpy.management.CalculateField, or separately?

Comment: `expression` needs to end up as a string containing valid python code that can be parsed standalone.  Try `expression = "'{}' + '!match.Filename!'".format(output_folder)`

Comment: @mikewatt Thank you for the help! That expression returns the correct complete path, but with some extra character surrounding the match.Filename part (e.g., C:/Users/ellah/Downloads/outu"3_in.png" where it should be C:/Users/ellah/Downloads/out/3_in.png). Do you know how to remove the u and the ""s?

Comment: If output_folder = "C:/Users/ellah/Downloads/" then set the expression = "'{0}'!match.Filename!".format(output_folder) you are getting the u" because you are wrapping the !match.Filename! in ' ' instead of using the pure value from the !match.Filename! field.

Comment: Hmm, well where is `match` coming from in the first place?  That looks like a unicode string got improperly string-ified prior to being fed into any of this, but Arc Pro uses Python 3 and the `u`-prefixed unicode strings aren't a thing in Python 3 anymore.  Assuming those characters really do appear in the source data, a hack might be to do `expression = "'{}' + '!match.Filename!'[2:-1]".format(output_folder)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example

[image]

Running the code below with !filename! field within the ' ' in the expression.

```
arcpy.management.CalculateField('in_features', 'filepath', "'{0}!filename!'".format(output_folder))
```

[image]

look at the difference in the expression !filename! field is outside of ' '

```
arcpy.management.CalculateField('in_features', 'filepath', "'{0}'!filename!".format(output_folder))
```

[image]